# Cut corners from rectangle to get box with max volume

Tags: calculus, derivatives, rectangles

[image]

I've got a rectangle (no informations about the box, volume box etc.). I need to find how much should I cut from the rectangle to get a box with maximum volume, so I need to find $x = ?$

At the moment I got to: $V(x) = (a-2x)(2a-2x)x = 4x^3 - 6ax^2 + 2a^2x$ and interval $[0,a/2]$.

$V'(x) = 12x^2 - 12ax - 2a^2$

How should I find $x$ now? I'm not really sure how should I continue.

Thanks.

Comment: $12x^2−12ax−2a^2 = 0$ apply the quadratic formula.  Solve for x in terms of a.  One of your answers will be greater than a/2 and can be discarded.

Comment: $x = (12a - \sqrt{240a^2})/24 = (1/2 - \sqrt {15}/6)a$  however, looking at your work, you have flipped a sign... so this answer isn't quite right.

Comment: Got it. It's $12x^2 - 12ax + 2a^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a\space\wedge\space x\in\mathbb{R}^+$:

- $$\text{V}(x)=x\left(a-2x\right)\left(2a-2x\right)$$
- $$\text{V}'(x)=2\left(a^2-6ax+6x^2\right)$$

Now solve $\text{V}'(x)=0$:

$$2\left(a^2-6ax+6x^2\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$a^2-6ax+6x^2=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Use he quadratic formula:

---

$$x=\frac{a\left(3\pm\sqrt{3}\right)}{6}$$

Comment: Check your signs.  x < a/2

Comment: So $x = a(3 - \sqrt{3}/6)$ is true? Because $x = a(3 + \sqrt{3}/6) \in [0, a/2]$.

Comment: you have a parenthesis that is not correctly located, but basically, yes.